# Why phpspec does not see shouldBeLike for object from static constructor?

Tags: php, phpspec

I'm trying to spec value object with static constructor in phpspec and the problem it says that `shouldBeLike` is undefined method. The object returned from `times` method is new Money, so I don't know what is wrong...

#### MoneySpec:

```
<?php

namespace spec;

use Money;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;

class MoneySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(Money::class);
    }

    function it_multiplies()
    {
        $five = Money::dollar(5);
        $five->times(2)->shouldBeLike(Money::dollar(5));
        $five->times(3)->shouldBeLike(Money::dollar(6));
    }
}
```

#### Money:

```
<?php

class Money
{
    private $amount;

    private function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public static function dollar($amount)
    {
        return new Money($amount);
    }

    public function times($multiplier)
    {
        return new Money($this->amount * $multiplier);
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For named static constructors you need use [`beConstructedThrough`](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/cookbook/construction.html#using-a-factory-method) (or one of the shorter syntax described). For example, with your case:

```
function it_multiplies()
{
    $this->beConstructedThrough('dollar', [5]);
    $this->times(2)->shouldBeLike(Money::dollar(5));
    $this->times(3)->shouldBeLike(Money::dollar(6));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You didn't define it... I can't see it in the code